# Changing header height with iText

Tags: itext

This is my first post on SO, so please be gentle :). I'm going to go ahead and apologize for how vague this will probably sound and for the lack of code (this is for work, and I am forbidden from posting it). I will try to pseudocode it or explain it as best as I can, but I have no choice in not being able to show code.

The customer wants a report that pulls data from a DB, so I will have no way of knowing how many pages will be in the form. There are essentially 2 sections of the form. My problem is that the headers have different heights.

The first page of the report's header is built like this:

1. report header
2. additional info 1
3. additional info 2
4. column header

The rest of the first section leaves out the Additonal Info 1 and Additional Info 2 tables and only has the report Header and Column Header, thus not needing as much space as the header on the first page. But the problem is that I don't know how to shrink the header size. The second section's header is even smaller.

What I have tried so far:

- Changing the value for the number of rows in my writeSelectedRows() depending on the page.
- Setting the height of the header to a smaller size (before calling document.newPage() since I've seen in my days of google searching for this topic that the header height has to be set before calling newPage())
- Adjusting the top margin size of the document depending on which section it is on

None of this even worked. I realize this is incredibly vague and there is probably no way anybody could answer this based on what I've written. I guess I am just asking if anybody knows any links to similar problems I could check out. I have spent days googling this topic and have read tons on it, but still have nothing that works. I have read through all of the relevant tutorials on the iText page. Still nothing that suits what the customer is wanting.

I have looked over possibly using ColumnText and PdfReader/PdfStamper(the "second pass" scenario), but I don't think I can use the ColumnText option since the headers have tables of varying cell widths and the like, and the "second pass" option doesn't leave me with a way to know which section of the report I am on (as far as I can tell).

Any advice or help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: I'm not exactly a newbie to iText, but I am certainly not an expert. Probably not even an intermediate. Just thought I needed to say that.

Comment: I'm not exactly a newbie in iText and you could say I'm THE expert. I've tried reading your question twice. It probably has too many words for others to read it, and not the right words for me to understand what you want to achieve. If your employer had a support contract, I'd do an extra effort, but... in its current state, I don't know where to begin asking counter-questions so that you clarify the terminology you're using. For instance: aren't you confusing the concept "header" with the concept "margin"?

Comment: Third attempt at reading your question: are you by any chance looking for the SetMargin() method in the Document class? It's like the only answer that would make sense, after decoding the question.

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded yet. I thought that it was set to notify me by email when somebody responds. You are most definitely right in that my question is horrendous! I just reread it and I confused even myself. When I said 'header', I mean that there will be data/information printed at the top of the pages. My problem is that each section of my form has a different header (with differing number of rows), and I will not know how many pages each section will be since the data for each section is pulled from a database.

Comment: I was well aware that my question was going to be very confusing since I couldn't post any code. When I posted it, I was also pounding my head against my desk, so the stress probably didn't help with writing the question. I am trying various ways to get around changing the header height for all of the sections at the moment and hopefully I can figure a way around it. Thank you for even ATTEMPTING to answer my question. (And I've been reading lots of information and tutorials you have written. You obviously are "THE expert" and I very much appreciate you even ATTEMPTING to answer me!)

Comment: Page headers are done with page events. It's a no-brainer to have the onEndPage() method create a different header for a different section. However: that doesn't explain why you're talking about forms and rows. Also it doesn't explain why you worry about not knowing the number of pages/sections/whatever in advance. It's still hard to determine what you're asking that is different from the standard functionality everybody has been using for many years.

Comment: When I said 'form', I am talking about a report the customer wants printed using a particular database. Thank you for your time, but as you said, it is hard for anybody to determine what I am asking about without including code, details, etc. that I am forbidden from giving out/unable to give out. I am sorry for all of the confusion, and I seriously appreciate the time you've taken to respond to me. It is amazing that anybody, much less you, even responded to my confusing, garbled mess of a question!

Comment: So it's not a form. It's content based on database records. Remove every reference to form in your question. When you say form, everybody will assume that you're talking about AcroForm technology or in your case XFA as you're saying the content grows dynamically. There's a simple solution to your problem about not being able to share code: buy a support contract with iText and we'll sign an NDA.

Comment: Ok, I will edit out the word 'form'. That is the terminology used for the reports we are creating, so I guess it was ingrained in me. I can see how that made it even more confusing than it already was. My bad, and thank you so much for pointing that out! I am a very low man on the totem pole here, but I will mention the iText support contract with my manager. Thank you, again, and sorry (again) for the confusion of my posts!